# how to validate keys with whitespaces in pydantic

Tags: python, json, pydantic

I have a json key with whitespace in it:

```
My_dict = {"my key": 1}
```

I want to create a `Model` to model it:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel
class MyModel(BaseModel):
    mykey: int
    # my key isn't a legit variable name
    # my_key is, but like mykey - it doesn't catch the correct key from the json

MyModel(**my_dict)
```

This doesn't work.

I tried playing with the `BaseModel.Config`, but didn't get anywhere. Didn't see anything on the [docs](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/models/) as well.

Is this possible?

I can use a workaround: Go over the `json`, replace all key's whitespaces into underscores, and then use `pydantic` but I would love to not use this...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it's possible by using Field's aliases:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field


class MyModel(BaseModel):
    mykey: int = Field(alias='my key')

    class Config:
        allow_population_by_field_name = True


print(MyModel(**{"my key": 1}))
print(MyModel(**{"mykey": 1}))
```

[Edit [@Omer Iftikhar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10062600/omer-iftikhar)] For Pydantic V2:

You need to use `populate_by_name` instead of `allow_population_by_field_name` otherwise you will get following warning

```
UserWarning: Valid config keys have changed in V2:
* 'allow_population_by_field_name' has been renamed to 'populate_by_name'
```

Comment: Be sure to allow `allow_population_by_field_name` to the config for this not to throw an error.

Comment: @yaakovBressler I didn't config and it worked just fine...

Comment: This is needed if you want to populate by `mykey` too (not only by "my key").